# What to do when nsp find a vulnerability in a dependency of a dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, winston, npm-update

I ran nsp on a project I'm about to deploy and i got this vulnerability

```
 Name          │ mime
 CVSS          │ 7.5 (High)
 Installed     │ 1.2.11
 Vulnerable    │ < 1.4.1 || > 2.0.0 < 2.0.3
 Patched       │ >= 1.4.1 < 2.0.0 || >= 2.0.3
 Path          │ myProject@1.0.0 > winston-s3@1.0.0 > winston@0.7.3 > request@2.16.6 > form-data@0.0.10 > mime@1.2.11
 More Info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/535
```

Now i understand that i need to update "mime" dependency but my problem is that the vulnerability is inside a dependency of a dependency of a dependency.

My 'winston-s3' dependency is up-to-date, when I'm going to 'node_modules/winston-s3/node_modules/winston/' there is no 'node_modules' directory and the "mime" dependency in the the main 'node_modules' directory is up-to-date so i guess that winston-s3 is not using this code.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks alot!